# Searching for a method to create Objects with dynamic Hitbox and Graphic

Tags: java, graphics

I am searching for a method to create an object like for example a ball that can be deformed when it hits the ground. I was searching Goole for a solution but didn´t find anything. Do you know like a Tutorial or at least an approach on how to create such an Object in a Java Application?

Edit:
In particular i dont have any idea how to store a complex 2D form, so that i can render according to it, and most importantly, use it for collision detection.

Comment: You're definitely going to need a physics engine if you want this behaviour. Maybe check out [Libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

Comment: I am already using libGDX and i also have experience with Box2d, but those physics engines are more for the movement of an object and not so much for the transformation of it.